# Flutter: Setting up own Rest API json file

Tags: ios, node.js, json, flutter, api

I'm trying to figure out what's the best and easiest way to set up my own json file and loading it up so everyone who uses my flutter app can access it. I'm relatively new to flutter and programming.
What is the best way to do that? I've seen some tutorials of people who already have an URL from some third party so they can easily show the data on their apps. For what I want to do, there is no such API, so I have to set it up on my own and fill it with my own data.
Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Depends. If you want to be able to update the JSON file without having to push a new version of your app, you will need to drop the JSON file on your own web server. The you can load that using the [Http Package](https://pub.dev/packages/http) or however you want to do networking. Otherwise, you can drop the JSON file into the `assets` folder in your project and configure your `pubspec.yaml` to use assets.

Comment: Yes, I don't want to push a new version of the app everytime I add new data to the json file. So there is no other way to set up my own web server? For example is there some kind of service provider where I can just upload my json file and then get the URL from this service provider? I really don't now anything about security features, so setting up my own server might be a little difficult..

Comment: There are services available. Anywhere that you can save your own files that allows direct access to the files. For Example: GitHub. Post your JSON there in a public repository. Then you can use the URL github provides to the raw file. E.G. https://raw.githubusercontent.com/angular/angular.js/master/.eslintrc-base.json

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try this solution out and let's see if I'm able to do it

Answer (score 1):

```
1) Setting up the Project:
//Install the HTTP dependency and add it in pubspec.yaml file in order to use API in the application.

dependencies:
  http:
2) Creating a Request:
//This basic request uses the get method to fetch the data from the specified URL in JSON format. Each request returns a Future<Response>. A Future<> is used to represent a potential value or error that will be available at some time in the future. For example, you made a request to a server now the response will take less than a few seconds. This time is represented from Future<>. Here, we use the async & await feature which ensures that the response is asynchronous. It means that until & unless we get the response, it will not move further.

Future<List<Fruit>> fetchFruit() async {
final response = await http.get(url);
}
String url = "Your_URL";

3) Creating the Classes:
//Create a Fruit class & save it as fruit.dart as shown below:

class Fruit {
final int id;
final String title;
final String imgUrl;
final int quantity;

Fruit(
this.id,
this.title,
this.imgUrl,
this.quantity,
);
factory Fruit.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
return Fruit(json['id'], json['title'], json['imgUrl'], json['quantity']);
}
factory Fruit.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
return Fruit(json['id'], json['title'], json['imgUrl'], json['quantity']);
}
}

4) Create Class objects:
//Create the FruitItem in fruitItem.dart

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'fruit.dart';

class FruitItem extends StatelessWidget {
FruitItem({this.item});

final Fruit item;

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Container(
padding: EdgeInsets.all(2),
height: 140,
child: Card(
elevation: 5,
child: Row(
mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
children: <Widget>[
Image.network(
this.item.imgUrl,
width: 200,
),
Expanded(
child: Container(
padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
child: Column(
mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
children: <Widget>[
Text(this.item.title,
style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
Text("id:${this.item.id}"),
Text("quantity:${this.item.quantity}"),
],
)))
]),
));
}
}

5) Create a List of fruits:
//Create a FruitList class in fruitList.dart as shown below:

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'fruit.dart';
import 'fruitItem.dart';

class FruitList extends StatelessWidget {
final List<Fruit> items;

FruitList({Key key, this.items});
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return ListView.builder(
itemCount: items.length,
itemBuilder: (context, index) {
return FruitItem(item: items[index]);
},
);
}
}
6) Displaying the Responses:
Display the response on the screen from main.dart file as shown below:

import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'fruit.dart';
import 'fruitItem.dart';
import 'fruitList.dart';

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
final String title;
final Future<List<Fruit>> products;

MyHomePage({Key key, this.title, this.products}) : super(key: key);

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) 
{
return Scaffold(
appBar: AppBar(
backgroundColor: Color(0xFF4CAF50),
title: Text("GeeksForGeeks"),
),
body: Center(
child: FutureBuilder<List<Fruit>>(
future: products,
builder: (context, snapshot) {
if (snapshot.hasError) print(snapshot.error);
return snapshot.hasData
? FruitList(items: snapshot.data)
: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
},
),
));
}
}
```